# What do you call it when you come up with a phrase to fit an acronym?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

You see this in marketing sometimes, where a product or company with an acronym name later comes up with a phrase that fits the acronym for an ad campaign or a related product.

For example, if your company name is QP, after the founder Quincy Peterson, your marketing department might make a "Quality Products" campaign. Or they might name the new adhesive product "Quick Plastic."

Is there a word or phrase that describes this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called a *backronym* or *bacronym*:

> A backronym, or bacronym, is a constructed phrase that purports to be the source of a word that is an acronym.

<sub>(source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Backronym))</sub>

They give the AMBER Alert as an example; it was named after a girl whose name was Amber, but constructed the phrase "America's Missing: Broadcast Emergency Response" to fit the abbreviation.

Comment: I don't think I disagree with your answer, but you might want to include a little more information.  The process which you've described whereby the non-acronym "Amber" was turned into an acronym ("Amber Alert" -> "A.M.B.E.R. Alert") seems quite different from the process of redefining the meaning of an existing acronym ("**Q**uincy **P**eterson" -> "**Q**uality **P**roducts").  However, it may be the case that "backronym" is the word used to describe both making an acronym from and non-acronym **and** redefining an existing acronym.